# Using REPLACE within Oracle CASE statement

Tags: oracle

`mytext` is a column in `mytable` containing the values `('ABC123','ABC456','Alphabet 123','Alphabet 456', 'DEF123' ...)`, but I want them all to be formatted as `'ABC123'`.  I can't get the syntax right

```
UPDATE mytable 
  SET mytext = 
     CASE
       WHEN (mytext like 'Alphabet %') Then REPLACE(mytext, 'Alphabet ', 'ABC')
       WHEN (mytext like 'Dookickey %') Then REPLACE(mytext, 'Doohickey ', 'DEF')
       WHEN (mytext like 'Goofiness %') Then REPLACE(mytext, 'Goofiness ', 'GHI')
       ELSE -- I want no other rows to be processed
     END;
```

Comment: `UPDATE mytable 
  SET mytext = REPLACE(mytext, 'Alphabet ', 'ABC')` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply using:

```
 UPDATE mytable SET mytext = REPLACE(mytext, 'Alphabet ', 'ABC')
```

Should work as `REPLACE` will leave the value intact if there is no match. However, this will touch *all* rows in your table, replacing some values by themselves -- which, at the very least, is not very efficient. In addition, this will replace any occurrence of the world `Alphabet`, even if not at the start of the string.

If you need something more robust, you should add a filter:

```
 UPDATE mytable SET mytext = REPLACE(mytext, 'Alphabet ', 'ABC')
   WHERE mytext LIKE 'Alphabet %'
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/16512/1

---

As the question was edited to support multiple replacement strings, you could indeed use a `CASE` statement:

```
UPDATE mytable 
  SET mytext = 
     CASE
       WHEN (mytext LIKE 'Alphabet %') THEN REPLACE(mytext, 'Alphabet ', 'ABC')
       WHEN (mytext LIKE 'Dookickey %') THEN REPLACE(mytext, 'Dookickey ', 'DEF')
       WHEN (mytext LIKE 'Goofiness %') THEN REPLACE(mytext, 'Goofiness ', 'GHI')
       ELSE mytext
    --      ^^^^^^
    --   let unchanged
     END;
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/31531c/1

As with my first solution, this will touch *all* rows of your table. And as before again, you can use a filter to avoid that. In that case, the `ELSE` clause is not longer necessary (since non-matching rows are left untouched):

```
UPDATE mytable 
  SET mytext = 
     CASE
       WHEN (mytext LIKE 'Alphabet %') THEN REPLACE(mytext, 'Alphabet ', 'ABC')
       WHEN (mytext LIKE 'Dookickey %') THEN REPLACE(mytext, 'Dookickey ', 'DEF')
       WHEN (mytext LIKE 'Goofiness %') THEN REPLACE(mytext, 'Goofiness ', 'GHI')
     END
  WHERE mytext LIKE 'Alphabet %' 
     OR mytext LIKE 'Dookickey %' 
     OR mytext LIKE 'Goofiness %';
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/44846/1

Comment: You second option with the where clause is my preference.

Comment: @Patrick I agree with you. I would reserve the first solution for a quick update of a test table for example. But for production code, I would only use the second form.

Comment: Thanks... I was unclear why I wanted to use a case statement.  With help, I updated my post to reflect the operation I am attempting... there are many more values in  mytext than I initially let on.  Thanks for the replies.

Comment: @mfrancis Check my update. You were _very_ close to the solution!

Comment: Thank you Sylvain... I can sleep tonight :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SUBSTR function in the CASE statement to check the first N characters.

You may have to adjust the number of characters being compared: in this example, the CASE will match only up to the first 8 characters:

```
    select CASE SUBSTR("FIELD1", 1, 8) 
           --    12345678
           WHEN 'OLD_TEXT'    THEN REPLACE("FIELD1", 'OLD_TEXT', 'NEW_TEXT')
           WHEN 'ALPHABET'    THEN REPLACE("FIELD1", 'ALPHABET', 'ABC')
           ELSE "FIELD1"   -- For all other values, leave unchanged
           END
    from
    ( 
      select
      'OLD_TEXT1' "FIELD1"
      FROM DUAL
      UNION
      select
      'OLD_TEXT2' "FIELD1"
      FROM DUAL
      UNION
      select
      'ALPHABET' "FIELD1"
      FROM DUAL
      UNION
      select
      'DNR1' "FIELD1"
      FROM DUAL
      UNION
      select
      'DNR2_DO_NOT_REPLACE' "FIELD1"
      FROM DUAL
    )  ;
```